# Can't install my own Firefox AddOn (File seems to be corrupt)

Tags: testing

can't install my own Extension on Firefox 64. I tested it succesfully in debug mode. Now I have big problems while installing: Corrupted! I don't know what to do. Studied all documentation. No success. I zipped the whole folder with all files and renamed it into *.xpi!

## File structure

```
icons/cancel.png 
close.js 
install.rdf 
install.xpi 
manifest.json
```

## close.js

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
      }
    }
  }

sleep(1000);
if (
    (
      document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText
    ).indexOf('Live your life') > -1
  ) {
    window.close(); 
}
```

## manifest.json

```js
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "pm",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Schließt nach 121 Sekunden",
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/"],
        "js": ["close.js"]
      }
    ],
    "icons": 
        {
            "64": "icons/cancel.png"
        }
    }
```

## install.rdf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>xyz@gmx.de</em:id>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <!-- Angaben zu unterstützten Anwendungsversionen --> 
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>64.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <!-- Sichtbare Daten -->
    <em:name>sample</em:name>
    <em:description>A test extension</em:description>
    <em:creator>Your Name Here</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.example.com/</em:homepageURL>
  </Description>      
</RDF>
```

Comment: You should use the "edit question" feature to add new details to your question instead of adding multiple answers. If you answer your own question, others will be less inclined to provide their own. Always be clear with your question and remember SO is not a 'bug-fixing' service!

Answer (score 1):

- No install.rdf needed
- Unique identifier needed, see mozilla forum for further infos
- LogOn and Register the Addon in the developer Forum Mozilla.